# C# Как ждать событие от WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, webbrowser, события

Добрый день!
Задача: перейти на сайт, заполнить поля формы входа, нажать на кнопку, дождаться перехода на страницу, дождаться загрузки страницы, дождаться загрузки данных в div-контейнер, далее ждать изменения в этом контейнере, как только изменится, считывать содержимое html тэга, и снова ждать изменений...

```
<div class="container">
            <audio id="notification">
                <source src="../notify.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
                <source src="../notify.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
            </audio>
            <div class="col-lg-pull-12 text-center mid-text">
                <h4>Live Binary Option Signals</h4>
                <span>for</span>
                <span id="last-update">2017-07-20 12:24:14</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-pull-12 sub-heading active-signals" style="display: none;">
                <h4>Signals — Active</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="active-list" class="col-lg-pull-12 active-signals" style="display: none;"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-pull-12 sub-heading inactive-signals" style="display: none;">
                <h4>Signals — Not Active</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="inactive-list" class="col-lg-pull-12 inactive-signals" style="display: none;"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-pull-12 sub-heading winning-signals">
                <h4>10 Most Recent Winners</h4>
            </div>
</div>
```

Нашел, что можно ожидать "onpropertychange", но куда его вкарячить не понимаю(
То что нашел:

```
var body = wb.Document.GetElementById("targetId");
body.AttachEventHandler("onpropertychange", AjaxContainerLoadData);
clickLink.InvokeMember("click");

private void AjaxContainerLoadData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var wb = sender as WebBrowser;
    ...
}
```

здесь, как я понял, это событие ожидается после клика на кнопку, а у меня не будет клика на кнопку, у меня не будет ни каких изменений, страница не меняется, url не меняется, однако на странице происходят визуальные изменения, меняется содержимое элемента (id="last-update"). 
Нашел событие WebBrowser.TextChanged, но и его тоже нужно откуда-то начинать слушать.

Мой код:
вызываю форму из консоли и далее обработка нажатия кнопки на форме:

```
private void Start_Login(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= Start_Login;

                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("txtEmail").SetAttribute("value", "email");
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("txtPassword").SetAttribute("value", "pass");

                Console.WriteLine("start waiting...");
                Console.WriteLine(webBrowser1.Version);
                //нет смысла ждать, но лучше подождать...
                Thread.Sleep(2000);

                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("btnLogin").InvokeMember("Click");

              webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += 
                new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(GetUPD);

        }

private void GetUPD(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000); //ждём загрузки div-контейнера
            Application.DoEvents(); //только после этого заполняются все контейнеры на странице

            string last_up = ((WebBrowser)sender).Document.GetElementById("last-update").GetAttribute("InnerText");
            Console.WriteLine(last_up);
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= GetUPD;

        }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted +=
                new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(Start_Login);
            WebBrowserHelper.FixBrowserVersion();
            webBrowser1.Navigate("https://app.binarysignalapp.com/");

        }
```

Comment: Вам не `WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted` нужен?

Comment: нет, не то, документ и так и меня уже "Completed" и он не изменяется. Меняется только содержимое контейнера, прилетает ajax'ом или хз.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, ваш вопрос по javascript? Почему тогда в тегах c#?

Comment: @test123 если вы про тэги, которые указаны в первом блоке с кодом, то я их взял со страницы сайта, в js не рублю, как это всё на сейте работает не понимаю. Весь остальной код, верно в С#, так как я использую C#, webBrowser.

Comment: Я про теги вопроса. Ajax подразумевает js, вы ждёте пока скрипт сайта завершит некую процедуру, делаете какое то действие и опять ждёте результата от js. Не проще ли напрямую послать команду компоненту браузера в виде js? Там же вы легко сможете распарсить данные.

Comment: @test123 суть в том, что я не хочу в цикле бесконечно чекать страницу каждую секунду - это не гуд. хочется это реализовать через `event`. И вот мои поиски пришли только к тому, что есть ивенты связанные только с загрузкой страницы или кликом на какие-то элементы. А у меня просто содержимое тэгов меняется, и я ищу способ обработать такое событие и обработать его в программе написанной на С#

Comment: Нажимая на кнопку и используя Ajax - вы явно посылаете http запрос, будь то get/post не важно, как и не важно sync/async. Во всех случаях работает не шарп, а скрипт сайта. Я рекомендую вам думать на этом уровне. Ни о каких циклах я вам не говорил. Можно обратиться к браузеру и попросить выполнить ваш js код, можно зарегистрировать слушателя, если вам это так нужно. В общем, решается проблема на уровне js, а не шарпом, так как ваш браузер не знает как и когда происходит этот запрос, это знает js скрипт сайта. Есть ли у сайта библиотеки?

Comment: Если используется XMLHttpRequest/ActiveXObject можно на них листенеры навесить, если какой fetch, аналогично. В общем, вопрос явно лучше задать тем кто работает с js.

Comment: Простой алгоритм, который должен быть вам понятным: 1. Формируем скрипт инжекции слушателя в ajax. 2. Вызываем у браузера выполнение вашего сгенерированного скрипта. 3. Навешиваем интерфейс слушателя вашего js листенера через компонент WebBrowser, чтобы отлавливать callback работы скрипта шарпом (c#), который вы заинжектили

Comment: @test123 я к сожалению плохо понимаю как работают ajax'сы, и как проверить есть ли библиотека у сайта...

Comment: @test123 значит, мне нужно на js написать слушателя, и заставить браузер выполнить этот js...я прочёл ваш последний комментарий, мне стало плохо)) видимо пойду читать, и если что-то буду не понимать буду писать вам. Спасибо за ответы, и ответы в будущем!